# Using vector in with NDK and OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, vector, android-ndk

I want to use vector class in my project. I have added the stl libs into C++ path. When I change *APP_STL := stlport_static* ndk shows errors in Opencv sdk for android. Here is my Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include ~/Android/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
LOCAL_MODULE    := GetImage
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := GetImage.cpp ImageProcessing.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And Here is the content of my Application.mk

```
 APP_STL := gnustl_static
 #APP_STL := stlport_static
 APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
 APP_PLATFORM := android-8
 APP_ABI := all
```

Any help would be much aprreciated

Comment: Maybe your question should be "can I use NDK stlport with OpenCV"? BTW, the answer to this question is plain and firm "negative". OpenCV expects **gnustl_static**.